# What is a minister in Hinduism called?

Tags: avatars

What is a minister or pastor in Hinduism called?

Are there support groups or someone I can meet with?

Comment: A purohit or guru is similar.

Comment: If you are westerner, ISKCON satsangs are probably closest to what you're looking for since many other westerners also join there for bhajan (choir), paat (scripture study) and pravachan (discourse)

Comment: you may also visit ramakrishna mission or sivananda ashrams

Comment: What is a minister or a pastor? Can you add a definition too? It'll help us to answer your question.

Comment: It depends upon the sect and school of philosophy and how some of the original organizers setup the sect. Some have no organization or congregations. Some are highly organized, some have literally no organization.